# how deploy() in web3 works?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, ether, ethers.js

I've been trying to understand how the deploy() in web3 works, but I can't find any source that helps me. I wanna know how deploy() in web3 interacts with Ethereum blockchain and deploys a smart contract. please help me understand the flow,
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is deploy(). it creates a transaction. Deployment of a smart contract is done by sending a transaction to the network with bytecode.

```
Contract.prototype.deploy = function(options, callback){

    options = options || {};

    options.arguments = options.arguments || [];
    options = this._getOrSetDefaultOptions(options);


    // throw error, if no "data" is specified
    if(!options.data) {
        if (typeof callback === 'function'){
            return callback(errors.ContractMissingDeployDataError());
        }
        throw errors.ContractMissingDeployDataError();
    }

    var constructor = this.options.jsonInterface.find((method) => {
        return (method.type === 'constructor');
    }) || {};
    constructor.signature = 'constructor';

    return this._createTxObject.apply({
        method: constructor,
        parent: this,
        deployData: options.data,
        _ethAccounts: this.constructor._ethAccounts
    }, options.arguments);
};
```

this is `deployData: options.data` actually the `bytecode`. we are sending the bytecode to evm and evm stores it in an address then we interact with this bytecode